# List Parent Child tree structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have multi tier parent-child relation and I want to list them in a tree structure.I have table with fields like id,parent_id.I have tried like

```
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM list WHERE parent_id = 0';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'].'<br>';
    $child1_sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE parent_id = ".$row['id'];
    $result1 = mysql_query($child1_sql, $link);
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $id = my_recursive_function($row1['parent_id'],$link);
        echo $id;
    }
}   

function my_recursive_function($parent_id,$link) {

    $child2_sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE parent_id = ".$parent_id;
    $result2 = mysql_query($child2_sql, $link);
    $row_cnt = mysql_num_rows($result2);

    if($row_cnt > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            if($row['parent_id'] == 0) {
                return $row['id'];
            } else {
                my_recursive_function($row['parent_id'],$link);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is giving me

```
Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 126877696) (tried to allocate 24 bytes)
```

Comment: try to increase memory limit: ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

Comment: I think It is not the solution because I have already changed it.

Comment: then you have to optimize you script :)

Comment: The links returned by internet search: 'php mysql generate menu' may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you should than optimize sql query, rather then use php recursion. There is one good article about that, maybe it can help you:

http://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html